# Como faço para conectar remotamente no Git

Tags: git, github, versionamento

Já sei para que utilizamos versionamento, como fazer commits, add novos files, logs, etc. mas eu gostaria de subir os meus arquivos no repositório do Github online, como eu faço para conectar e enviar meus arquivos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alexander, suponho que você já tenha uma conta no GitHub...

Então é o seguinte:

- Primeiramente gere o par de chaves ssh: `ssh-keygen -t rsa`

PS: Se você não tiver o `ssh`, deve instalar

- Você cria um repositório no GitHub para este seu projeto
- Copia a url que ele gerar. Alguma coisa do tipo:
  https://github.com/usuario/nome_do_projeto.git
- Então no teu git local, dê o comando: `git remote add origin https://github.com/usuario/nome_do_projeto.git`

PS: origin é apenas um nome padrão você pode colocar qualquer nome. Ele será o nome do teu repositório remoto

- Então você dá o comando: `git push origin master`
- Informa a senha e pronto.

Answer (score 3):

Configurar o cliente GIT, para vincular os commits ao nome correto ( Autor dos commits)

```
git config --global user.name "SEU NOME AQUI"
git config --global user.email email@gmail.com
```

Para inicializar o repositório GIT vazio existe duas formas.

[1] Executando o comando abaixo, que o git vai criar a pasta, caso ela não existir e inicializará como repositório GIT. Ex:

```
~$ git init name_project
```

[2] Criar a pasta e depois entrar na pasta e depois inicializar o repositório, ficaria assim:

```
~$ mkdir name_project
~$ cd name_project
~$ git init
```

Entre em seu repositório e crie o arquivo README

```
~$ cd name_project/
~$ vim README
```

Escreva um texto inicial, como por exemplo “First commit” e salve o arquivo (:wq)

```
~$ git status
```

Aparecerá a os dados conforme imagem abaixo, mas o que isso quer dizer? Bom, a parte importante dessa tela é Untracked files que mostra os arquivos que o GIT ainda não está gerenciando, ou seja, o GIT não sabe o que fazer com ele e não registra nenhuma modificação no arquivo.

depois basta adicionar e comitar o arquivo:

```
~$ git add README
~$ git commit -m "Adicionando arquivo README"
```

Próximo passo é subir para o repositório com:

```
~$ git push
```

Se queres baixar em um servidor ou em outro computador use o comando:

```
~$ git clone [url]
```

(essa url é dada no diretório que foi criado)

Depois de clonar para baixar atualizações use:

```
~$ git pull
```